# I use class to create an object in react component but when I try to set the state to the new object it doesn't rerender the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

I use a class to create an object in react component but when I try to set the state to the new object it doesn't rerender the component

Class:

```
class persons {

constructor(list = {}) {
this.list = list
} 

getPersons() {

return this.list
}
 
addPerson(person) {
this.list[someId] = person 
} 

}
```

in component when I add new person and set the state to the new list it didn't rerender the component like that:

```
//... 
const [personsList , setPersonsList] useState({}) 

const persons = new Persons(personsList)

persons.addPerson({name: "Mike"})
setPersonsList(persons.list)
//it doest also rerender with that

persons.addPerson({name: "Mike"})
setPersonsList(persons.getPersons)
//..
```

Although when I log persons.list or persons.getPersons() It shows the new list with the added person

Comment: It’s the same list reference so it doesn’t know it needs to re-render.

Comment: So how to let it know that the list is updated to rerender the component?

Comment: This is covered in most React tutorials; there are several ways it can be handled, but the simplest is to always create a new array, like by setting it to `[…oldArray, newData]`. There’s other options.